# geom_vline Median not consistant with True Median of Vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a vector

```
var = c(5, 3, 6, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 6, 3, 15, 1, 0, 2, 3, 
1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 6, 4, 3, 0, 7, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 10, 
13, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4, 2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 3, 1, 
7, 4, 0, 1, 7, 1, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1, 9, 2, 0, 4, 3, 5)
```

I am plotting the distribution of the histogram using ggplot and drawing a vertical line of the median. The median of var equals 3(doubled checked using python numpy)

```
groupMedian <- median(var)

print(groupMedian)

df <- data.table(x = var)

df <- df[, .N, by=x]

df$x <- factor(df$x, levels=c(0:25))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=N)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1.0, 
     colour = "darkgreen",
     fill = 'lightslateblue')

p <- p + labs(title = "Var Histogram", 
          x = "x", 
          y = "Frequency") +
   scale_x_discrete(drop=FALSE) +
   geom_vline(xintercept=groupMedian, 
         colour = 'red', size = 2) 

 p = p + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 50)) + 
     scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 50, 2))

 p = p + theme(panel.grid.major = 
            element_line(colour = "black", linetype = "dotted") )


 ggsave("barplot.png", p, width=8, height=4, dpi=120)

 print(p)
```

The median is 3 but the line is placed at 2.

I also tried using

```
p = p+ geom_vline(data=var,
          aes(xintercept = median),
          colour = 'red', size = 2 )
```

Comment: The problem is that you turned the x-axis into a factor. R starts with an index of 1, not zero, so the third level has a value of 2. Here's the proof: `levels(df$x)[3]` which yields `[1] "2"`

Comment: @Chase is there any way around this besides doing something like
geom_vline(xintercept=groupMedian +1)

Comment: sure - just outlined how i'd approach this problem, avoiding the conversion to factor.

Answer (score 3):

You can let ggplot2 do the aggregation for you and just you `geom_histogram()` instead. This seems to provide the gist of what you're after:

```
#load data.table
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(x = var)
groupMedian <- median(var)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1,
                 colour = "darkgreen",
                 fill = "lightslateblue",
                 origin = -0.5) + #this effectively centers the x-axis under the bins
  geom_vline(xintercept = groupMedian,
             colour = "red",
             size = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,25), 
                     limits = c(0,25))
```

Giving you something like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The reason I used the previous method was because when I need the bins to center underneath the x axis tick.

Comment: @user5219 - adjust the `origin`, see the help manual for more details: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_histogram.html. Also here's a general discussion for this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/hFxDohloTSw. I updated the code above to reflect this, but not the image.